# change url and access to file by htacess

Tags: .htaccess, url

My real url is:

```
/a/bc/de/test/1.jpg
```

I want access to my file by this url without redirect:

```
/abcde/test/1.jpg
```

How can i do that?

Comment: More information is needed. What is static about that URL? Are there always `/a/bc/de` at the prefix? Can those be any three directory values? Can it ever be more than 3 directories? Is `test/` always present?

Comment: just need to set /a/bc/de replace with /abcde/ (always are 5 charachters and hex) and all of them are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty strange rewrite rule but you can try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z])([a-z]{2})([a-z]{2})/(test/.+)$ /$1/$2/$3/$4 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tanx for help, this is correct:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-f]{1})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})/([0-9a-z-]{1,})/(.+)$ /$1/$2/$3/$4/$5 [L,NC]
```